# Saving an array in JSON in ionic

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I have wrote a code like below to concatenate two arrays together and save them as a JSON file.
In this code, "seg" is an array of some number, which has been produced somewhere in my code. info is also an array containing some data following by "Seg" array.

Defining variable types:

```
seg: Array<any> = [];
info: Array<any>=[];
final: Array<{info:any, Seg:any}>=[];
```

push value in array and concatenate them together:

```
this.info.push({date_created: 25 , description: 'aaa', year:'2015'});
this.final.push({info: this.info   ,Seg:this.seg});
this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, 'test.json', JSON.stringify(this.final));
```

the produced file is something like this:

```
[{"info":[{"date_created: 25 , "description"="aaa", "year" :"2015"}],"seg":[2,3,4,5]}]
```

As you can see, the info information is placed between two bracket, so JSON file consider it as a list, not record.

Does anyone knows , how can I remove this brackets from the info array sides?
Should change the type of variable from array to anything else?

Comment: If you only want **one object**, change the type from array to object. Stripping the brackets from the output doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this to store as a record

```js
seg: Array<any> = [];
info: Array<any>=[];
final:{info:any, Seg:any};

this.final.Seg = this.seg;
this.final.info = this.info;
```